# Why can't I add item meta after order is complete?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to be able to add meta data to each item in an order after payment is complete. The following is the code I have so far:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', array($this, 'action_fuck_it_all'));

public function action_fuck_it_all($order_id)
{
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $item_id = $item['item_id'];
            $licence = $this->_getProductLicenseCode($product_id);
            if( !$licence ){
                return false;
            }
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'attribute_licence_code', $licence->licence_code);
            $this->_setLicenceCodeStatus($licence->licence_id, 'assigned');
        }
}
protected function _getProductLicenseCode($product_id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT licence_id, product_id, licence_code, licence_status FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_licences 
                WHERE product_id = $product_id
                AND licence_code <> '' 
                AND licence_status = 'available'
                ORDER BY creation_date ASC
                LIMIT 1";
    //print $query.'<br/>';
    return $wpdb->get_row($query);
}
protected function _setLicenceCodeStatus($licence_id, $status)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $data = array('licence_status' => $status);
    if( $status == 'assigned' )
    {

    }
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'wc_product_licences', 
                    $data, 
                    array('licence_id' => (int)$licence_id));
}
```

As per my testing, everything appears to work (getting license, setting license, changing license status to assigned, etc.) except the license code is not inserted as meta for each item. Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: nice function name

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it on an other hook, for example this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'my_order_item_meta'), 10, 2);

function my_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    $product_id = $values['data']->id;

    $licence = $this->_getProductLicenseCode($product_id);
    if( !$licence ){
        return false;
    }
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'attribute_licence_code', $licence->licence_code);
    $this->_setLicenceCodeStatus($licence->licence_id, 'assigned');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok here 
item_id is not inside $items it is key of $items

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', array($this, 'my_machine'));
    public function my_machine($order_id)
    {
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $items = $order->get_items(); 
            foreach ( $items as $key=>$item ) {
                $product_id = $item['product_id'];
                $item_id = $key;
                $licence = $this->_getProductLicenseCode($product_id);
                if( !$licence ){
                    return false;
                }
                woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'attribute_licence_code', $licence->licence_code);
                $this->_setLicenceCodeStatus($licence->licence_id, 'assigned');
            }
    }
```